# copy column from 1 df to another based on condition

Tags: pandas, postgresql

I have a situation,there are 3 columns(x,y,point) in my dataframe and I am copying id table from another df,but problem is that all columns have different values in them .I want to copy id column with point col such that point 1,2,3 have same id.
df is

```
x           y                 point
76.32       42.58              1
86.34       90.02              2
687.12      125.327            1
65.28       87.11              2
963.1       854.2              3
```

```html
id colum from df1
M123
P478
Q145
J768
D476
```

expected output is

```
x           y                 point     id
    76.32       42.58              1    M123
    86.34       90.02              2    M123
    687.12      125.327            1    P478
    65.28       87.11              2    P478
    963.1       854.2              3    P478
    85.23       96.23              1    Q145
```

I am trying this code

```
df1["id"]=  df["id"]
```

and output is

```
x           y                 point     id
    76.32       42.58              1    M123
    86.34       90.02              2    P478
    687.12      125.327            1    Q145
    65.28       87.11              2    j768
    963.1       854.2              3    D476
    85.23       96.23              1    P145
```

there are hundreds of rows in df so i cannot give row position. Is there any  way to do it? any help will be appreciated

Comment: left join with key cols would be suitable solution.

Comment: `df['point']=df['id'].eq(1).cumsum().astype(str).mul(3)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each group starting by `1` then is possible use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by dictionary, each group is created compare by `1` with [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) and [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
df['id'] = df['point'].eq(1).cumsum().map(dict(enumerate(df1['id'], 1)))
print (df)
        x        y  point   id
0   76.32   42.580      1  111
1   86.34   90.020      2  111
2  687.12  125.327      1  222
3   65.28   87.110      2  222
4  963.10  854.200      3  222
5   85.23   96.230      1  333
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['point'].eq(1).cumsum())
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    2
5    3
Name: point, dtype: int32
```

Or if necessary check difference between groups:

```
df['id'] = df['point'].diff().lt(0).cumsum().map(dict(enumerate(df1['id'])))
print (df)
        x        y  point   id
0   76.32   42.580      1  111
1   86.34   90.020      2  111
2  687.12  125.327      1  222
3   65.28   87.110      2  222
4  963.10  854.200      3  222
5   85.23   96.230      1  333

print (df['point'].diff().lt(0).cumsum())
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    2
Name: point, dtype: int32
```

Comment: @user19 - orignal DataFrame is `df`, new is `df1` with column `id` in my answer. There is some problem?

Comment: @user19 - Can you changed data in question like comment above?

Comment: @user19 - Solution in my answer working for changed data same very well

Comment: @user19 - What is `dict(enumerate(df1['id'].head(), 1))` ?

Comment: It should be `print (dict(enumerate(df1['id'].head(), 1)))
{1: 'M123', 2: 'P478', 3: 'Q145', 4: 'J768', 5: 'D476'}`

Comment: @ jezrael if i try to add prefix with column value, df['id'] = df['point'].eq(1).cumsum().map(dict(enumerate("AB_"+df1['id'].astype(str), 1))) it gives output as  AB_111.0, AB_222.o. do you have any idea why it is adding ".0" ?

Comment: @user19 - first try change `.map(dict(enumerate("AB_"+df1['id'].astype(str), 1)))` to `.map(dict(enumerate("AB_"+df1['id'].astype(int).astype(str), 1)))`, if not working try `.map(dict(enumerate("AB_"+df1['id'].astype('Int64').astype(str), 1)))` - last working in pandas 0.25+

Comment: it is throwing following error "Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer"   although there are not NAN values

Comment: @user19 - You can count missing values by `df1['id'].isna().sum()`

Comment: @user19 - `.map(dict(enumerate("AB_"+df1['id'].astype('Int64').astype(str), 1)))` not working?

Comment: @user19 - Never seen error before, maybe some data related issue?

Comment: If use `"AB_"+df["id"].astype(str).map(str))+("_"+ df1["point"].astype(str)` it working?

Comment: hmm, not missing last `)` or `))`  ?